# How can I automatically center an image?

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment

I use:

```
\documentclss{mwrep}
...
\begin{figure}  
\includegraphics{a.jpg}
\caption[Long caption]{Caption}
\label{pic-a}
\end{figure}
```

How can I make images to be always visible on the center of page? (To be more specific: the center of the image should be between the left and right margin - I use different left and right margins).
I don't want to put anything after every `\begin{figure}` in my document.

Important: I don't want to waste an entire page on a single image at the very center of the page. I want only horizontal alignment. (left <-> right)

Comment: insert `\centering` after `figure`

Comment: Yes, that works. But I want to do this without adding anything to every figure in document.

Comment: Regarding your 2nd question: Use either the `caption` or the `hypcap` package.

Comment: My example results in a top-aligned float, so you must be doing something different. (And without a minimal example it's hard to tell what exactly you're doing different.)

Comment: `caption` and `hypcap`... none of them helped...

Comment: Please don't ask two questions in one post. Centering the figures and fixing the hyperlinks are two different things. I suggest removing the second question here and reask it as a new question.

Comment: @Ichibann: Also try to create a truly minimal example -- one that doesn't load packages not relevant for the question and, more important, that doesn't rely on external files availabele for you, but not for other users.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

With regard to your first question: Use the [`floatrow`](http://ctan.org/pkg/floatrow) package -- it centers the content of floats by default.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\begin{document}

The first paragraph.

\begin{figure}  
\includegraphics{a.jpg}
\caption[Long caption]{Caption}
\label{pic-a}
\end{figure}

And the second.

\end{document}
```

If you don't want to load `floatrow` for whatever reason, you may instead add the following to your preamble (thanks to egreg for the tip):

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset\centering
\makeatother
```

EDIT: The figure in my example only was vertically centered because I had not added any dummy text. Example corrected.

Comment: What does `draft` do? I was told that `graphicx` is better. How to use `draft` in `graphicx`?

Comment: Also, it centers image at the page as whole. I want only to center vertically. There could be more text or images on the same page.

Comment: @Ichibann It does not require an input file and shows a bounding box with its name instead, hence you can render the document as is. The usage with `graphicx` is the same.

Comment: `draft` makes the example compilable even if there is no file `a.jpg` in one's working directory. ;-) This feature is also part of `graphicx`.

Answer (score 21):

Add the following to your document preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset{\centering}
\makeatother
```

The *start* of every float construction *ends* with a macro `\@floatboxreset` that looks like this (from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)):

```
\def \@floatboxreset {%
        \reset@font
        \normalsize
        \@setminipage
}
```

Executing the above suggestion adds `\centering` at the end of `\@floatboxreset`, effectively changing it to

```
\def \@floatboxreset {%
        \reset@font
        \normalsize
        \@setminipage
        \centering
}
```

which removes the requirement to specify `\centering` all the time.

Answer (score 13):

If you're using the `memoir` documentclass, global float adjustment may be set using: `\setfloatadjustment{<float>}{<adjustment>}`. For example,

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\setfloatadjustment{figure}{\centering}
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}  
    \includegraphics{image}
    \caption[LoF caption]{Regular caption}
    \label{fig:image}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9):

You could redefine the `figure` environment to include the `\centering` command:

```
\let\origfigure\figure
\let\endorigfigure\endfigure

\renewenvironment{figure}[1][tbph]{%
    \origfigure[#1]%
    \centering
}{%
    \endorigfigure
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way to center all images, is to use `\adjincludegraphics` from the `adjustbox` package and declare the `center` to be used for all of them after any local options. However, this will add `center` also to all other `\adjustbox` macros and `adjustbox` environments. I actually just like to show the principle:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}% for fummy text only
\usepackage[draft]{graphicx}% remove 'draft' for a real document
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\adjustboxset*{center}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
\adjincludegraphics[width=5cm]{a.jpg}
\caption[Long caption]{Caption}
\label{pic-a}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}
\adjincludegraphics{b.jpg}
\caption[Long caption]{Caption}
\label{pic-b}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3]

\begin{figure}
\adjincludegraphics{c.jpg}
\caption[Long caption]{Caption}
\label{pic-c}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```