# Centering all images

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, floats

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I automatically center image?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23078/how-can-i-automatically-center-image)

How can I align center all picture :

```
\begin{figure}‎
‎‎\centering‎  % I want do not use this line for every images
‎\includegraphics[]{a‎}‎‎
‎\caption{dsafkjtfdgkajhg‎}‎‎
‎\end{figure}‎‎
```