# How can I automatically center all floats including subfloats?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, subfloats

This is a follow up to [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23078).

I am using this in my preamble:

```
\makeatletter   % inserts a "\centering" to every floatbox.
\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset\centering
\makeatother
```

I am having two question for the use of this:

- How can I implement the same thing for subfigures, too? It works fine for all floats, but not for minipages or subfigures (from `subcaption`, which are minipages as well).
- How can I switch of this behavior locally?

Here is some code for playing around:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset\centering
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.48\linewidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{qwertz}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[b]{.48\linewidth}
        %\centering
        \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{qwerty}
    \end{minipage}
    \caption{Caption}%
    \label{fig:label} 
\end{figure}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most recent versions of `subcaption` provide a `\@subfloatboxreset` hook.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\makeatletter % inserts a "\centering" to every floatbox.
\g@addto@macro\@floatboxreset{\centering}
\g@addto@macro\@subfloatboxreset{\centering}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]

X\dotfill X

\begin{subfigure}[b]{.4\linewidth}
  X\dotfill X

  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{qwerty}
\end{subfigure}\qquad
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.4\linewidth}
  X\dotfill X

  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{qwerty}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Caption}\label{fig:label} 
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

### Original answers follow

If you're willing to use `subcaption`, then

```
\g@addto@macro\subcaption@minipage\centering
```

should work for `subfigure` and `subtable` environments.

---

#### Added November 13, 2013

A revision of `subcaption` has made `\subcaption@minipage` a macro with arguments, so the above patch doesn't work any more and

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\apptocmd\subcaption@minipage{\centering}{}{}
\makeatother
```

becomes necessary.

---

I wouldn't add `\centering` to the code for general `minipage` environments, even locally in a float, because they might pop up in unexpected places when using macros that exploit `minipage` in their code.

You could use a “local” version of `\g@addto@macro` for adding `\centering` to all `minipage` environments in a float; `\appto` of `etoolbox` is good for this:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\gappto\@floatboxreset{\centering\appto\@minipagerestore{\centering}}
\makeatother
```

but I wouldn't do it, as this would mean that *all* minipages in a float would get `\centering`; there are macros that internally use `minipage` that might be used in a float: also those would receive `\centering`, which could so end up in unwanted places.

Comment: Yes, I am willing. And always do. So thank you very much for solution and explanation. The point "even locally in a float" is not clear to me. Shouldn't I use the syntax provided in my OP? Do you have a solution for my second question? I will happily mark this as an answer then.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I've added how you *could* do it; but, please, don't, for the reasons I explain.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wasn't aware that someone is using the internal macro `\subcaption@minipage` otherwise I would have tried to avoid that change. However, I think introducing something like `\@subfloatboxreset` which could be patched more easily would be a good idea!?

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt That's *really* a good idea. Maybe also an interface for getting automatic centering? It seems wanted by many people.

Comment: `\subcaption@minipage` is no longer used. do `\apptocmd\subcaption@iiminipage{\centering}{}{}` worked for me in 2020. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/144853/62285

Answer (score 6):

You could insert the following instructions in the preamble of your document to center-set the contents of `table`, `figure`, `subtable`, and `subfigure` environments. To affect the positioning of the latter two environments, it is assumed that the `subcaption` package is loaded.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@xfloat}%
  {\@floatboxreset}%
  {\@floatboxreset\centering}{}{}
\patchcmd{\subcaption@minipage}%
  {\setcaptionsubtype}%
  {\centering\setcaptionsubtype}{}{}
\makeatother
```

The first macro that's patched, `\@xfloat`, is defined in the LaTeX kernel; the second patched macro, `\subcaption@minipage`, is provided by the `subcaption` package.

Comment: @krnk - The diagnostic remark "didn't work" isn't very specific. Which document class do you use? Do you load a package, such as `subcaption`, that provides environments named `subtable` and `subfigure`?

Comment: @krnk - Thanks for pointing out that the code was no longer working. (I think the `subcaption` package was revised substantially in late 2013, but I hadn't taken note of the consequences for my answer until just now.) I've rewritten the patching commands; please let me know if things are OK now.