# Add \centering to all subfigures in subcaption using \g@addto@macro

Tags: floats, horizontal-alignment, subcaption

I'm trying to center `subcaption` subfigures as outlined [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134886/36301).

However, compilation fails with

```
! Argument of \subcaption@minipage has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.6 \g@addto@macro\subcaption@minipage\centering

? 
Process interrupted by user
```

Any ideas?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\subcaption@minipage\centering
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
\large A
\subcaption{A subfigure}\label{fig:1a}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[b]{.5\linewidth}
\large B
\subcaption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:1b}
\end{minipage}
\caption{A figure}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\g@addto@macro` is for macro with no arguments. But, `\subcaption@minipage` is a macro with two arguments. Try (untested) `\renewcommand*\subcaption@minipage[2]{\minipage#1{#2}\captionsetup{subtype}\centering}` (check no spaces at all in definition after copy paste from here). Ok I tried (on an old TeX installation). It seems to work with `usepackage{caption}` added (maybe as old installtion) and the above within `makeatletter...\makeatother`

Comment: [again, this is on an old distribution, perhaps definition of `\subcaption@minipage` has changed since]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function `\g@addto@macro` can only be used with parameterless macros.

You'll be luckier with `\apptocmd` from `etoolbox`:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd\subcaption@minipage{\centering}{}{}
\makeatother
```

but, of course, you have to use `subfigure` and not `minipage`.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd\subcaption@minipage{\centering}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
\large A
\subcaption{A subfigure}\label{fig:1a}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
\large B
\subcaption{Another subfigure}\label{fig:1b}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{A figure}\label{fig:1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In year 2020, `subcaption` is using `minipage` instead of `subcaption@minipage` to create a new "sub-" environment.
This means `\apptocmd\subcaption@minipage ....` would not alter the actual behavior of the package, since `\subcaption@minipage` is never used.

From the source of `subcaption` version 1.3 -

```
\caption@For{subtypelist}{%
  \newenvironment{sub#1}%
    { ....
       \subcaption@iminipage
      ....}%
    {\subcaption@endminipage
     \endminipage}}%
\def\subcaption@iminipage[#1]{%
  \caption@withoptargs{\subcaption@iiminipage{#1}}}
\newcommand*\subcaption@iiminipage[3]{%
    ....
    \minipage[#1]#2{#3}%
    ....}
```

Patching `subcaption@iiminipage` achieves the same thing as done seven years ago.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\apptocmd\subcaption@iiminipage{\centering}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1][1-2]

\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
    B
    \caption{A}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]