# Append \centering to \begin{subfigure} (from subcaption package)

Tags: subcaption, etoolbox

How can I append `\centering` to `\begin{subfigure}` (from *subcaption* package)? I tried using the `etoolbox` , but for some reason it won't work for the `subfigure` enviroment (only working for the `figure` enviroment).

Here a MWE to demonstrate my problem.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[margin=1em]{subcaption}

\usepackage{mwe}


\apptocmd\figure{\centering}
\apptocmd\subfigure{\centering}



\begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
        \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}
        \caption{qqq qqq qqq qqq qqq qqq }
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}
        \begin{subfigure}{4cm}
            \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}
            \caption{abc abc abc abc abc  }
        \end{subfigure}%
        \begin{subfigure}{4cm}
            \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}
            \caption{abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc }
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{qqq qqq qqq qqq qqq qqq }
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

result (with image a, b misplaced):

[image: result]

I also tried `\AtBeginEnvironment{subfigure}{\centering}` and to manually patch it with `\let`, but no luck.

Comment: Have you tried `\AtBeginEnvironment{subfigure}{\centering}`?

Comment: Yes, but also not working. I also tried the manually with `\let`, but no luck. (sry, forgot to mention that in the question)

Comment: @someonr You're forgetting that `\apptocmd` has *four* arguments (usually the last two are `{}{}`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your patch to `\figure` is not correct: you lose the possibility of specifying the float positioning argument, so no `\begin{figure}[htp]` with that.

It's better to go deeper. I propose two patches for `figure`: the first adds `\centering` only to it (uncomment the three lines if you want it), the second just adds it to all floats.

It's difficult to distinguish between `subfigure` and `subtable`. The patch for centering them can be found in [Add \centering to all subfigures in subcaption using \g@addto@macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144853/add-centering-to-all-subfigures-in-subcaption-using-gaddtomacro)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% Do the patch before loading caption!

% This patch adds \centering only to figure
%\apptocmd{\@xfloat}{\position@float{#1}}{}{}
%\def\position@float#1{\csname position#1\endcsname}
%\def\positionfigure{\centering}

% This patch adds \centering to all floats
\appto\@floatboxreset{\centering}
\makeatother

\usepackage[margin=1em]{subcaption}
\makeatletter
\apptocmd\subcaption@minipage{\centering}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}

\caption{qqq qqq qqq qqq qqq qqq }

\end{figure}

\begin{figure}

\begin{subfigure}{4cm}
  \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{abc abc abc abc abc  }
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{4cm}
  \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}
  \caption{abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc }
\end{subfigure}

\caption{qqq qqq qqq qqq qqq qqq }

\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Note that you *must* patch `\@xfloat` before loading `subcaption` or `caption`.

[image]

Comment: Thx, for the working patch. How did you know the commands to patch? By reading the source or is there some shortcut ;) ? Since the macros aren't part of the "public interface", this could break with any update?

Comment: @someonr `\@floatboxreset` has been there from the beginning; for `subfigure` I believe that Axel has some ideas about an interface.

Comment: @egreg -- although what you have is what was in the original question, it would look nicer if the bottoms of the subfigures were aligned, and similarly, the top lines of their captions.

Comment: @barbarabeeton It suffices to use `\begin{subfigure}[t]{4cm}` in both; this assuming that the two pictures have the same height.

Comment: Once again, a tabular would work better than subfigure.

Answer (score 2):

Speaking of using a tabular...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}

\null\vfil\begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image}
        \caption{qqq qqq qqq qqq qqq qqq }
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
            \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}&
            \includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-b}\\
            (a) abc abc abc abc abc&
            \parbox[t]{4cm}{(b) abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc abc}
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{qqq qqq qqq qqq qqq qqq }
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: tabular]

Comment: why the figures go to the top of tha page instead of being in the middle of the text I would like to put them?

Comment: Vertical position is controlled by the options of figure[tbhp].  I modified the above to center the "text" and use the "here" option.  A more reliable method would be to use one full page figure (with multiple captions).