# Automatically centering subfigures where the includefigure width is less than the subfigure width

Tags: horizontal-alignment, subcaption

Helloo everyone,

I've been working with this community for quite a while now. Thanks for that!
But now I seem to have run into a problem mentioned nowhere else. To be more precise, none of the solutions worked for my case.

What I want to do is automatically centering the content of the `subfigure` environment from the `subcaption` package in the entire document. I've seen the answers from [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144857) and [Mico](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134889), and this works just fine for a normal `figure` environment. However, I want to include figures with less than `width=1\linewidth`, causing the included figures within the `subfigure` to be left-aligned. If I use the `\centering` command manually, everything works fine.

I think the problem is that patching the subfigure somehow fails, as can be seen form my auxiliary variable/commands `\figureOK` and `\subfigureOK`. But that's where I'm stuck.

Following Mico's approach for the `figure` (or rather all floats), I also tried to use `\@subfloatboxreset` suggested by Axel Sommerfeldt (in the [comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134886/207986)) and provided by `subcaption`. But this seems to have no effect at all.

I hope my problem becomes clear.
Here is a (hopefully) minimal working example.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\providecommand{\figureOK}{\relax}
\providecommand{\subfigureOK}{\relax}


%%%------------------------------------------------------ Anwser from egreg
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144857
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
    % Try to patch floats to use \centering
    \apptocmd\@floatboxreset{\centering}            % Try Patch
    {\renewcommand{\figureOK}{Yes}}                 % Execute on success
    {\renewcommand{\figureOK}{No}}                  % Execute on failure

    % Try to patch subfigure to use \centering
    \apptocmd\subcaption@minipage{\centering}
    {\renewcommand{\subfigureOK}{Yes}}
    {\renewcommand{\subfigureOK}{No}}
\makeatother
%%%------------------------------------------------------


%%%------------------------------------------------------ Answer from Mico
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134889
%\usepackage{etoolbox}
%\makeatletter
%   % Try to patch floats to use \centering
%   \patchcmd{\@xfloat}%
%       {\@floatboxreset}%                  % Replace this      % Also tried this with \@subfloatboxreset
%       {\@floatboxreset\centering}         % With this
%       {\renewcommand{\figureOK}{Yes}}     % On success
%       {\renewcommand{\figureOK}{No}}      % On failure
%   
%   % Try to patch subfigure to use \centering
%   \patchcmd{\subcaption@minipage}%
%       {\setcaptionsubtype}%
%       {\centering\setcaptionsubtype}
%       {\renewcommand{\subfigureOK}{Yes}}
%       {\renewcommand{\subfigureOK}{No}}
%\makeatother
%%%------------------------------------------------------



%%%------------------------------------------------------ For Test only
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.4pt}
%%%------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
    \section{Debug}
    Figures automatically centered? \figureOK

    Subfigures automatically centered? \subfigureOK

    \section{Tests}
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \includegraphics[width=0.25\linewidth]{example-image-A}
        \caption{Patching figures works well}
    \end{figure}
    \vfill
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
            \centering      %   <-- This is what I want to get rid of
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-B}
            \subcaption{A subfigure}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
            \centering      %   <-- This is what I want to get rid of
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-C}
            \subcaption{Another subfigure}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{A figure where subfigures are manually centered $\rightarrow$ works just fine}
    \end{figure}
    \vfill
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-B}
            \subcaption{A subfigure}
        \end{subfigure}%
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{.5\linewidth}
            \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-C}
            \subcaption{Another subfigure}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{A figure where subfigures should be centered automatically $\rightarrow$ doesn't work}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update:**
log files are [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiwMxTxJ6TwhgZgbgFaSluH7ipoENw?e=VwU47X) on OneDrive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\subcaption@minipage` is not defined, so you can't patch it. Use the same hook you are using for the main float:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
    % Try to patch floats to use \centering
    \apptocmd\@floatboxreset{\centering}            % Try Patch
    {\renewcommand{\figureOK}{Yes}}                 % Execute on success
    {\renewcommand{\figureOK}{No}}                  % Execute on failure

\apptocmd\@subfloatboxreset{\centering}{}{\fail} %<----
\makeatother
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to change anything at all. The subfigures without the explicit `\centering` command remain left-aligned.

Comment: It worked fine for me, show your log file.

Comment: Thanks! I updated my question with a link to the log file.

Comment: I get centered subfigures from your document, but my system is newer.

Comment: Thanks alot for the quick help! I updated my Miktex and it works like a charm now. Interesting enough, I freshly installed Miktex just last month.