# How to change default alignment for table environment in report class

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I am using the `table` environment in `report` class.
Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\hline
a&b\\
c&d\\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table name}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The output I am getting is a table with that is left aligned and a caption that is centred.
If I use `\centering` I can get the table centred.
However, I need to set each table separately in the `table` environment.

Which command I need to modify it so that all tables are centred?

Comment: Possible duplicate(s): [How can I center all tables in a document?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6033/5764); [How can I automatically center all floats including subfloats?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/134881/5764)