# Avoid repeating [hbt] and \centering for every table

Tags: tables, floats, automation, preamble

In a document I'm writing, I'm using the familiar [`[hbt]`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat) option for my floating tables, and I [center](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2651/should-i-use-center-or-centering-for-figures-and-tables) them. I'd like to avoid repeating that every time I'm creating a table. I assume it's easy to add something in my preamble that makes sure that these two options are used every time I begin a new `table` environment?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[hbt]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{*3{l}}
1 & 2 & 3\\
a & b & c\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You really should include `p`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Some people specifically say you shouldn't use ``p``: http://www1.maths.lth.se/help/latex/graphics/

Comment: https://xkcd.com/386/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Combining Werner's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/167868/9077) here with lockstep's [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23081/9077) to [How can I automatically center an image?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23078/how-can-i-automatically-center-an-image), we can do it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{floatrow} % this automatically centers all floats
    \floatplacement{table}{hbtp} % all tables are given the [hbtp] option
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{*3{l}}
1 & 2 & 3\\
a & b & c\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: According to the documentation for `floatrow` it's an extension of `float` borrowing code from it, and you shouldn't load `float` as well.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek. `floatrow` doesn't load `float` but includes a modification of it, and its documentation says that you must not load `float`with it. It is a good idea to follow that.

Answer (score 24):

the default figure placement can be set with

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\fps@figure{htbp}
\makeatletter
```

(It's almost always a bad idea not to include `p` in the default)

For centering you can add it to `\@floatboxreset`

```
\makeatletter
\def \@floatboxreset {%
        \reset@font
        \normalsize
        \@setminipage
\centering%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
}
\makeatletter
```

Comment: This was a lot more complicated than I had anticipated. Is there no simpler way of saying "When you initiate the environment ``{table}``, automatically add ``[hbt] \centering``"? EDIT: I think that's exactly what Ethan Bolker did in his answer.

Comment: It couldn't be a lot less complicated could it? There is a single command that sets up formatting in floats and this adds `\centering` to it. It's just a direct implementation of the question?

Comment: @Sverre well the other answer (while perfectly usable) just wraps the table in a custom environment (beware of white space after it though:-) this one does more exact;y what you asked, which is to set the default placement and formatting for floats (which is normally set by the class)

Comment: By "complicated" I meant that the code is really hard for someone like me to understand and penetrate, since I have never seen commands such as ``\fps`` and ``\@floatboxreset`` before, and I'm sure I wouldn't be able to find out what they mean either.

Comment: @Sverre or Werner's answer which actually sets exactly the same commands as here, but using custom commands from float package, rather than lower level command definitions. (Probably you should accept that one:-)

Comment: @Sverre \fps isn't a command it is \fps@figure which is just defined exactly as I showed to be a collection of `htb` etc and is the default option for figures. so there is nothing to find out about it other than what is shown above, really no hidden magic:-)

Answer (score 21):

The [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) provides an interface to specify the float placement for a specific float using

```
\floatplacement{<type>}{<spec>}
```

The `\floatplacement` command resets the default placement specifier of a class of floats. So, one could use

```
\floatplacement{table}{hbt}
```

to achieve what you're after.

Comment: Can I use the same package to center all floats?

Answer (score 11):

Try

```
\documentclass{article}

\newenvironment{mytable}
{\begin{table}[hbt]
  \centering}
{\end{table}}

\begin{document}

\begin{mytable}
\begin{tabular}{*3{l}}
1 & 2 & 3\\
a & b & c\\
\end{tabular}
\end{mytable}
\end{document}

\end{document}
```