# Changing graphicx default float positioning

Tags: graphics, floats

I have the parameters [htbpH] to tell the figure environment, which float positions are allowed. Afaik, [tbp] is the default setup. I'd like to change it to [tp] by default, can you help me to achieve that?

I don't want to set the bottomnumber = 0, because in some special situations, I still want to be able to place a figure at the bottom, but I just don't want to allow this position by default.

The graphicx documentation unfortunately doesn't say anything about that.

Edit: Oh well, just recognized, why I didn't found anything about it... figure env != graphicx... I'll search for it again, but anyway, maybe you already know the solution and post it here...

Edit 2: Was easy... [What are the default placement options for a floating figure in Latex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172782/what-are-the-default-placement-options-for-a-floating-figure-in-latex)

Comment: See [Avoid repeating \[hbt\] and \centering for every table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/167863)

Comment: Based on the edit, it's a dupe

Comment: in addition to setting the defaults, note that  `[htbpH]` is an error: you can not include `H`  with other float parameters it has to be just `[H]` the whole point is that H makes it a non-float so combining with other options is not possible.