# renewcommand with begin{...}

Tags: floats

I'm trying to center all figures, but renewcommand does not work the way I expected.

```
\renewcommand{\begin{figure}}{\begin{figure}\centering}
```

This code has an error. Why doesn't it work and how can I make it work?

Comment: You might be interested in [How can I automatically center an image?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23078/134144)  and the various answers there.

Comment: the first argument of `\renewcommand` has to be a single token, the command name, not a fragment of code like `\begin{figure}` (which is 9 tokens)