# All the TikZ figure in \Large size

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a document containing lots of texts and figures. You see in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,
                shadows,
                shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\large 
\[
\tikzmarknode{A}{2} \tikzmarknode{B}{3} \times \tikzmarknode{C}{5}\tikzmarknode{D}{5}
\]
    
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\tikzset{
    every node/.style={outer sep=2pt},
    lab/.style={font=\tiny,inner sep=0pt}}
    \draw[blue] (A) to[out=90,in=90,looseness=1.4] node[lab,midway,above]{multiply} (D) ;
    \draw[red] (B) to[out=90,in=90] node[lab,midway,above]{multiply} (C) ;  
    \draw[cyan] (A) to[out=-70,in=-110] node[lab,midway,below left]{multiply} (C) ;
    \draw[cyan] (B) to[out=-70,in=-110] node[lab,midway,below right]{multiply} (D) ;        
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every text node part/.style={align=center}]
    \node (a) [rectangle,draw=none,fill=blue!25,rounded corners=0.1cm] at (0,0) {\Large 5 \\ {} \\ 3};
    \node (b) [rectangle,draw=none,fill=blue!25] at (1,0) { \Large 7 \\ {} \\ 6};
    \node (c) [rectangle,draw=none,fill=blue!25] at (2,0) {\Large 8 \\ {} \\ 2};
    \node (d) [rectangle,draw=none,fill=blue!25] at (3,0) {\Large 9 \\ {} \\ 8};
    \node (fol1) [rectangle,draw=none,fill=blue!25] at (0,-1.5) {\Large 8};
    \node (fol2) [rectangle,draw=none,fill=blue!25] at (1,-1.5) {\Large 13};
    \node (fol3) [rectangle,draw=none,fill=blue!25] at (2,-1.5) {\Large 6};
    \node (fol4) [rectangle,draw=none,fill=blue!25] at (3,-1.5) {\Large 17};
    \node (fol) [rectangle,draw=none,fill=blue!25] at (2,-2.5) {\Large 9377};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mycirc/.style={circle,fill=blue!20, minimum size=0.5cm}]
    \node[mycirc] (n1) at (-3,0) {116};
    \node[mycirc,label=above:{Middle number}] (n2) at (0,0) {120};
    \node[mycirc] (n3) at (3,0) {124};
    \node[rectangle,label=below:{Product},draw,minimum size=0.7cm] (n4) [below=0.7cm of n2] {\Large $120^2-2^2$};
    \draw[-to] (n1) -- node [midway,above] {less} (n2);
    \draw[-to] (n3) -- node [midway,above] {more} (n2);
    \draw[-to] (n2) -- (n4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}  

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

You may notice all numbers inside `tikzpicture` are in large font. I have to do it manually for every numbers writing each time the command `\Large`. **Is there any way to set globally the font size to `\Large` for all `tikzpicture`?**

### Related:

Also how to set all the `tikzpicture` to be centered that I made using `\begin{center}...\end{center}`?

Comment: Please don't edit your initial question with an additional one, either related or not. This new question, by the way, has nothing to do with Ti*k*Z, but could be dealt by setting a general option in your document. [See here, for instance](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23081/204164)

Comment: @SebGlav Got it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put

```
\tikzset{font=\Large}
```

before the first `tikzpicture`, for example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{font=\Large}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node  {Test};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For just a single `tikzpicture` you can do it as an optional argument to the environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font = \Large]
        \node  {Test};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

To centre all `tikzpicture`s use

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\begin{center}}
\AfterEndEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\end{center}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font = \Large]
        \node  {Test};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which, as the command names suggest, appends `\begin{center}` before starting a `tikzpicture` environment, and `\end{center}` after ending a `tikzpicture` environment. See the [etoolbox documentation](https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf) for more details.

Comment: That's great!!!