# etoolbox and beamer : why do I get an error?

Tags: beamer, etoolbox

This recent  [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/625397/centering-the-tikzpicture-elements) tickled my curiosity on `etoolbox` (that looks great but that I have actually never used).

After a quick check, I don't read any notorious incompatibility between `etoolbox` and `beamer`.

Where am I wrong when I try this ? Must be silly...

```
%\documentclass{memoir}
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

% This works fine
%\BeforeBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\begin{center}}
%\AfterEndEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\end{center}}

% It generates an error
%\BeforeBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\begin{frame}}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{ \begin{frame} \frametitle{My TikZ} }
\AfterEndEnvironment{tikzpicture}{ \end{frame} }

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[circle,draw=red] {Test};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: beamer frames are grabbed as a whole so the code needs to see `\end{frame}` explicitly in the document

Comment: @DavidCarlisle mmm... thanks boss :) So probably no by-pass to that I presume.

Comment: @JeT Try changing your definition to `\BeforeBeginEnvironment{tikzpicture}{\begin{frame}[environment=tikzpicture]\frametitle{My TikZ}}` (though I'm not sure it's a good idea to make all `tikzpicture`s do a frame...)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik  obrigado. You're right, bad idea but the example was simple enough as an exercise to try to understand this package.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik is it just me or I know get an error `Incomplete \ifx` ?

Comment: @JeT As I said, not sure if it's a good idea :)  the `environment` option works when you do `\newenvironment{myenv}{\begin{frame}[environment=myenv]}`.  It doesn't work when you use environment hooks (and I think it's not possible to make it work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

beamer frames are grabbed as a whole so the code needs to see `\end{frame}` explicitly in the document otherwise it will parse ahead past the end of the frame looking for `\end{frame}`.